# NodeJs - MySQL Error: Too many connections

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, node.js, mvc

Recentemente fiz um refactor do meu código para adotar o padrão MVC, pois o mesmo estava muito desorganizado!

Entretanto, começou a aparecer um erro chamado "Too many connections". Esse erro faz com que o meu node-mysql cai e não realize mais requisições até que eu restart o node.

Link do código: https://github.com/LeonardoVini/node-refctoring/blob/master/refctoring-backend.zip

Não sei o ES6 esteja causando isso ou eu tenha feito algo de errado.
Eu tentei diversas vezes arrumar este erro.

Erro que aparece:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código de conexão:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

const connMySQL = () => {
    return mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'eqix1998',
        database: 'quotedb',
        port: 3306
    });
}

module.exports = () => {
    return connMySQL;
}
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const consign = require('consign')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

consign()
    .include('app/routes')
    .then('config/dbConnection.js')
    .then('app/models')
    .then('app/controllers')
    .into(app);

module.exports = app;
```

Arquivo de rotas:

```
module.exports = (application) => {
    application.get('/quotes-createdBy/:username', (req, res) => {
        application.app.controllers.quotes_by_name.getQuotesByName(application, req, res);
    });

    application.get('/quotes-closed-createdBy/:username', (req, res) => {
        application.app.controllers.quotes_by_name.getClosedQuotesByName(application, req, res);
    });

    application.get('/quotes-qss-createdBy/:username', (req, res) => {
        application.app.controllers.quotes_by_name.getQSSQuotesByName(application, req, res);
    });
}
```

Arquivo de controller:

```
module.exports.getQuotesByName = (application, req, res) => {

    let username = req.params.username

    var connection = application.config.dbConnection();
    var quotes_by_nameDAO = new application.app.models.Quotes_By_NameDAO(connection);

    quotes_by_nameDAO.getQuotesByName(username, (error, results) => {
        if (error) throw error
        return res.send(results)
    });
}

module.exports.getClosedQuotesByName = (application, req, res) => {

    let username = req.params.username

    var connection = application.config.dbConnection();
    var quotes_by_nameDAO = new application.app.models.Quotes_By_NameDAO(connection);

    quotes_by_nameDAO.getClosedQuotesByName(username, (error, results) => {
        if (error) throw error
        return res.send(results)
    });
}

module.exports.getQSSQuotesByName = (application, req, res) => {

    let username = req.params.username

    var connection = application.config.dbConnection();
    var quotes_by_nameDAO = new application.app.models.Quotes_By_NameDAO(connection);

    quotes_by_nameDAO.getQSSQuotesByName(username, (error, results) => {
        if (error) throw error
        return res.send(results)
    });
}
```

Arquivo model:

```
function Quotes_By_NameDAO(connection) {
    this._connection = connection;
}

// Get quotes by nome - QuoteStatus = 'In Progress' OR QuoteStatus = 'Stand By'
Quotes_By_NameDAO.prototype.getQuotesByName = function (username, callback) {
    this._connection.query(`
        SELECT * FROM quotes
        WHERE
            (QuoteStatus = 'In Progress' OR QuoteStatus = 'Stand By')
        AND
            CreatedBy = ?
    `, username, callback)
}

// Get closed quotes by nome - QuoteStatus = 'Closed'
Quotes_By_NameDAO.prototype.getClosedQuotesByName = function (username, callback) {
    this._connection.query(`
        SELECT * FROM quotes
        WHERE
            QuoteStatus = 'Closed'
        AND
            CreatedBy = ?
    `, username, callback)
}

// Get QSS quotes by nome - QuoteStatus = 'Sent to QSS'
Quotes_By_NameDAO.prototype.getQSSQuotesByName = function (username, callback) {
    this._connection.query(`
        SELECT * FROM quotes
        WHERE
            QuoteStatus = 'Sent to QSS'
        AND
            CreatedBy = ?
    `, username, callback)
}

module.exports = () => {
    return Quotes_By_NameDAO;
}
```

Comment: Não consegue colocar o código de onde você faz a conexão aqui pra podermos avaliar?

Comment: Eu atualizei a pergunta com as infos. Eu deixei o link do git para vizualização

Comment: Vou reescrever uma parte da estrutura da sua aplicação, ok? A rota que você acessa fica como?

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo de como esta o meu routes, controller e model.

Comment: Opa... pode modificar o que necessário.
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é que sempre que invoca `application.config.dbConnection();` é criado uma nova conexão com o banco, em vez de exportar uma função que cria uma conexão, crie uma conexão e exporte ela diretamente:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

const connMySQL = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'eqix1998',
    database: 'quotedb',
    port: 3306
});


module.exports = () => {
    return connMySQL;
}
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda, vou testar aqui.

Answer (score 3):

Montei um exemplo com base no código que você enviou utilizando o `pool` de conexões do `MySQL`. No exemplo que coloquei haverá, no máximo, 10 conexões simultâneas. Isso quer dizer que as demais serão enfileiradas.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const quotes = require('./app/routes/quotes');

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use('/quotes', quotes);

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 9095, () => {
    console.log(`Node app is running on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

**app/routes/quotes.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const controller = require('../controllers/quotes');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', controller.list);

module.exports = router;
```

**app/controllers/quotes.js**

```
const model = require('../models/quotes');

const list = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.send(await model.list());
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e.message);
  }
};

module.exports = {
  list,
};
```

**app/models/quotes.js**

```
const { promisify } = require('utils');
const pool = require('./connection');

const list = async () => {
  const query = promisify(pool.query);

  return query('SELECT * FROM quotes');
};

module.exports = {
  list,
};
```

**app/models/connection.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'eqix1998',
  database: 'quotedb',
  port: 3306,
  connectionLimit : 10,
});

module.exports = pool;
```

Comment: vou testar aqui. Obrigado

Comment: Mas por que ter 10 conexões simultâneas? Uma já não é o suficiente?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam depende. Ngm vai chamar seu serviço simultaneamente?

Comment: Mas todas as requisições que acontecerem simultaneamente não podem usar a mesma conexão?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Podem, mas assim você irá enfileira-las. Assim se alguém fizer uma consulta pesada, todos os seus usuários deverão esperar que essa consulta seja finalizada antes de receber o retorno de seus serviços. Isso irá ocasionar uma fila que pode ficar grande dependendo do acesso aos recursos

Comment: Esse pool de conexões gerencia as que estão usadas e retorna sempre uma livre? Então um limite de 4 sria suficiente não? Já que, por padrão, o Node executa até 4 requisições simultaneamente e deixa as demais em um loop de espera

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam acho que o `Node` não realiza só 4 conexões simultaneamente não. E `suficiente` é relativo ao número de usuários, tamanho do seu sistema, velocidade de acesso aos dados, etc.